# Solr query syntax facet issues

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a solr server setup and am attempting to get facets working correctly, the following query

```
/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&indent=true?&facet=true&facet.field=style&facet.field=variety&facet.field=packsize&fq=packsize:6&fq=CABERNET
```

Where there are three facet fields "style, variety and packsize". The query above returns a number of correct results however when I execute this

```
/select?q=*:*&wt=xml&indent=true?&facet=true&facet.field=style&facet.field=variety&facet.field=packsize&fq=packsize:6&fq=variety:CABERNET
```

Suddenly I receive zero results why does prefixing "variety" to the fq break for this but not for packsize?

Also when trying to add &fq=style:red or &fq=red neither of these work even though there are many results with "style = red". Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the filter queries if the field is not specified, the query would work on the default field.
You can check the filter query executed by adding `debugQuery=on`

```
<arr name="parsed_filter_queries">
    <str>text:solr100</str>
</arr>
```

So check for the default field should have the CABERNET term.
Also the match would depend upon the field type, the analysis performed and where the field is indexed or not.
Only fields indexed would be able to filter the results.